# onclick method on a colorbar matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I have a colorbar and a graph. I was wondering if you can use the onclick method on a colorbar that will then do something on the graph.
So click on a particular color portion of the colorer then something happens
I know how to do the bit that i want to happen. I just want to know how to set the colorbar to allow on click

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure! Just do something like `cbar.ax.set_picker(tolerance)`.

As a quick example, this will highlight values in the image near the value you click on the colorbar:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.random((10,10))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(data)
cbar = fig.colorbar(im)
ax.set_title('Click on the colorbar')

highlight = ax.imshow(np.ma.masked_all_like(data), interpolation='nearest', 
                      vmin=data.min(), vmax=data.max())

def on_pick(event):
    val = event.mouseevent.ydata
    selection = np.ma.masked_outside(data, val - 0.05, val + 0.05)
    highlight.set_data(selection)
    fig.canvas.draw()

cbar.ax.set_picker(5)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', on_pick)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. I was trying to use mouse click events and realized that `event.inaxes` could never be `cbar.ax`, so a picker is a very nice solution.