# onclick function matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

```
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap([[1,0,0], [0,0,1], [0,1,0], [1,1,0]])

    self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
self.ax = self.fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
x_ax = self.fig.add_axes([0.05, 0.1, 0.05, 0.8])
x2_ax = self.fig.add_axes([0.05, 0.1, 0.05, 0.8])
y_ax = self.fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.05, 0.8, 0.05])
x_ax.imshow(xcolors, cmap=cmap, interpolation='none')
x_ax.set_aspect('auto')
x_ax.set_position((0.1,0.1,0.05,0.8))
y_ax.imshow(ycolors, cmap=cmap, interpolation='none')
x_ax.set_picker(5)
def on_pick(event):
    print hello


self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.fig)
self.canvas.mpl_connect('Pick_event',on_pick)
```

I am having trouble with my onclick method
basically I want to click on the colorbar and for it to print out hello
with the code i have, it does nothing 
what have I done wrong?

Comment: As general advice, it's better if you post code that people can run with out having to make any modifications (ie striping out all the `self` and providing reasonable fake data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary problem is that you are creating a new `canvas` instead of using the one `fig` already has.  There are (atleast) two ways to do what you want.

You can do this by setting the *images* to respond to the pick event (see [this tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/pick_event_demo.html) example 4):

```
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap([[1,0,0], [0,0,1], [0,1,0], [1,1,0]])

xcolors = arange(15).reshape(15,1)
ycolors = arange(15).reshape(1,15)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
x_ax = fig.add_axes([0.05, 0.1, 0.05, 0.8])
x2_ax = fig.add_axes([0.05, 0.1, 0.05, 0.8])
y_ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.05, 0.8, 0.05])
x_ax.imshow(xcolors, cmap=cmap, interpolation='none', picker=True)
x_ax.set_aspect('auto')
x_ax.set_position((0.1,0.1,0.05,0.8))
y_ax.imshow(ycolors, cmap=cmap, interpolation='none', picker=True)
def on_pick(event):
    artist = event.artist
    if isinstance(artist, matplotlib.image.AxesImage):
        im = artist
        A = im.get_array()
        print A.shape,
    print 'hello'


canvas = fig.canvas
canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event',on_pick)
```

Alternatively, you can set the *axes* to respond to the pick event (see [onclick method on a colorbar matplotlib python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910963/onclick-method-on-a-colorbar-matplotlib-python)) as such:

```
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap([[1,0,0], [0,0,1], [0,1,0], [1,1,0]])

xcolors = arange(15).reshape(15,1)
ycolors = arange(15).reshape(1,15)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
x_ax = fig.add_axes([0.05, 0.1, 0.05, 0.8])
x2_ax = fig.add_axes([0.05, 0.1, 0.05, 0.8])
y_ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.05, 0.8, 0.05])
x_ax.imshow(xcolors, cmap=cmap, interpolation='none')
x_ax.set_aspect('auto')
x_ax.set_position((0.1,0.1,0.05,0.8))
y_ax.imshow(ycolors, cmap=cmap, interpolation='none')

x_ax.set_picker(5)
y_ax.set_picker(5)

def on_pick(event):
    artist = event.artist
    if isinstance(artist, matplotlib.axes.Axes):

        print event.mouseevent.ydata,
        print event.mouseevent.xdata,
    print 'hello'


canvas = fig.canvas
canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event',on_pick)
```

Notice the difference in the type of artist that the event is carrying with it (and hence the information you have easy access to).