# displaying 2D array for checking the values of the cells

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I display a 2D array of scalars (with optimal cmap) and **the value of the cell displayed when moving the mouse over the displayed image**. `plt.imshow` of matplotlib does not seem to provide this.

Comment: this may give you some insight...[onclick function matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14923545/832621)

Comment: @SaulloCastro Adding more call backs is over kill here.

Comment: gah! wrong question, should be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754931/matplotlib-values-under-cursor/14755358#14755358

Comment: and  http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/image_zcoord.html