# how to find colour of colorbar matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython, colorbar

I have created a colorbar which has a variety of colours in it. I have set it to a pick event.
When I click on the colorbar, on a particular colour segment I want it to return the colour.
I tired using `event.artist.get_facecolor()` but it gave me the error `'Axes' object has no attribute 'get_facecolor'`

Comment: are you and miik in the same program?  You two seem to be asking very similar questions recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab the `ydata` (like in [onclick method on a colorbar matplotlib python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910963/onclick-method-on-a-colorbar-matplotlib-python)) and the run it through the color map.

If `cb` is your colorbar object

```
color = cb.cmap(cb.norm(event.mouseevent.ydata))
```

will return be the RGBA color associated with where you clicked.